# What is 'name' in M2Crypto Engine class methods

Tags: openssl, m2crypto

The following 3 Engine methods require 'name' as an argument.

```
load_private_key(self, name, pin=None)  
load_public_key(self, name, pin=None)   
load_certificate(self, name)
```

What exactly is 'name'?  From examples I've found it appears to be some type of slot id for the USB token.  How do I find the id?

Comment: These are just functions that M2Crypto passes directly to OpenSSL, so it would be better to ask with OpenSSL tag (or on openssl-users mailing list). Look up the Python source first, see which m2.* function is getting called, then look at the SWIG source _engine.i to see the corresponding OpenSSL function. In this case load_private_key is ENGINE_load_private_key. OpenSSL docs don't help much: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/engine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some information on the following website:  http://www.etokenonlinux.org/et/FAQ

```
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --slot 0 -O --login
```

In the ouput search for a private key object and its ID.

```
Private Key Object; RSA
  label:      eTCAPI private key
  ID:         39453945373335312d333545442d343031612d384637302d3238463636393036363042303a35
  Usage:      decrypt, sign, unwrap
```

When I use the ID from this command as the arg, I don't get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably referring to the private key file, public key file, and signed certificate respectively.  There are examples for creating those [at this site](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/).